# How Do You Make A Suggestion To Blender Developers?

Tags: workflow

I get it.  The Bender Foundation probably gets thousands of suggestions to "improve" Blender's work flow or capabilities.  But I haven't yet found where suggestions can be forwarded.  Any ideas?

I have several suggestions, but there doesn't seem to be a way to submit them or give the developers my opinion as to how important they are.

For example, I love the fact that Blend is constantly adding new capabilities, but I wish they would skip a cycle and just focus on improving the workflow.  Too many times I'm faced with multiple steps in different panels to create something.

In too many cases, Blender is like, "Oh, if you want to do that then you need to do the following 6 steps each and every time.

OK, I get it.  Not everyone needs to streamline workflow according to me.

So, Blender, give me a macro capability where I can "record" the six steps I normally need to take in standard Blender so I can execute a macro to automate my custom workflow.  If there is at time I only need 3 of the 6 steps then I can do it manually or record another macro.

Come on guys, there are many things I do routinely that requires a number of specific steps that are the same each and every time.  Give me a macro capability to automate my custom routines within Blender.

I have perhaps 3 or 4 more suggestions that I think would streamline workflows that I don't think would take much programming effort.

I hate having to memorize: first go to this panel and do this, then scroll down and do this and this and this, then go to another panel and do these two things, etc.

Give me a macro capability to record all of the steps once and use it a hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

Blender does include a macro capability - most of the operations you perform are output to a log window that's normally hidden off the top - drag the bottom edge of the top menu down to see it.

[image: log window]

When you perform an action you'll see the equivalent python call in the log. You can copy the command and paste it either into a Console window or into a Text Editor text block to run as a python script (give a name ending in '.py' to tell Blender it's python code.

For example, add a cube, scale it, rotate it :

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2, 1, 1), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=0.785398, axis=(0, 0, 1), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```